# Do CPU and main memory need drivers to work?

Tags: operating-system

Peripheral devices require drivers to work in a computer system (operating system).

Does a CPU need a driver to work?

Same question for a main memory?

Comment: drivers are just code. specialized code, but still code. how do you propose to load this "driver" onto a cpu if you need a driver to execute code on the cpu? can't load the driver without executing code, and can't execute code until this driver is loaded. so, no. you don't need a driver for a cpu, or memory.

Comment: Not really.  If the CPU is a part of a multi-core set of CPU's, then the OS would need a driver for interprocessor comms, but I don't think that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is **no**.

The reason is that the motherboard comes with an (upgradable) BIOS, which takes care of making sure the CPU features function correctly (obviously, an AMD processor won't work on an Intel motherboard). You can upgrade the BIOS, but that should be avoided until, ... reasons of course.
Same goes for memory, it does not require a driver either.

Just so that you know, if you ever tried overclocking you can notice that you can alter the way the RAM functions, ganged/unganged mods and so on. My point is that there is already an interface established using code allowing you to make changes in real time, isn't that the very purpose we even have drivers, to be able to use a peripheral with expected outcome.
On the other hand, peripheral devices are just extensions, which the motherboard does not know how to handle, hence needing a set of instructions i.e. drivers.

Answer (score 11):

In a modern system both memory and the CPU require kernel mode code — as do devices — to function.

Memory requires management of virtual memory tables. The CPU requires maintenance of process control structures.

In the business, such code is not called a "driver".

Generally, one thinks of a device driver as being kernel mode code that responds to devices through the interrupt vector.

That said, on some systems there are "printer drivers" that do not fit that definition of driver.

In short, do memory and CPU have something called a "driver"? No.
Do they have something analogous to a driver? Yes.